# LINQ group by with an aggregate function (method syntax)

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, method-chaining

I have this code here:

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of Object())
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)
Dim groupedindexes As New List(Of Integer)
Dim datarows As New List(Of DataRow)

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    dt.Columns.Add("f1", Type.GetType("System.Char"))
    dt.Columns.Add("f2", Type.GetType("System.Char"))
    dt.Columns.Add("f3", Type.GetType("System.Char"))
    dt.Columns.Add("f4", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    For i = 0 To 100
        dt.Rows.Add("a", "b", "c", i * 2)
    Next

    indexes.Add(0)
    indexes.Add(1)
    indexes.Add(2)
    indexes.Add(3)

    groupedindexes.Add(0)
    groupedindexes.Add(1)
    groupedindexes.Add(2)

    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        datarows.Add(dt.Rows(i))
    Next

    result = datarows.Select(Function(row) indexes.Select(Function(index) row(index)).ToArray)
    'select sum(f4), f1, f2, f3 from t1 group by f1, f2, f3
    Dim test = result.GroupBy(Function(Key) groupedindexes.Select(Function(groupedindex) Key(groupedindex)).ToArray,
                              Function(Result) indexes.Select(Function(index) Result(index)).ToArray)

End Sub
```

I'm trying the group by method/function. With the above code, I manage to get a test result, grouped by f1, f2 and f3. Now, I would like to implement the sum function, like the SQL query said:

```
select sum(f4), f1, f2, f3 from t1 group by f1, f2, f3
```

I tried something like this:

```
Dim test = result.GroupBy(Function(Key) groupedindexes.Select(Function(groupedindex) Key(groupedindex)).ToArray,
                          Function(Result) indexes.Select(Function(index) Result(index)).ToArray).Select(
                          Function(groupedrow) New With
                                               {Key .sum_of_f4 = groupedrow.Sum(Function(row) Convert.ToInt32(row(3))),
                                                Key .f1 = groupedrow.Key(0),
                                                Key .f2 = groupedrow.Key(1),
                                                Key .f3 = groupedrow.Key(2)})
```

But f4 isn't summed, I get all the 101 rows.

How should I correct my code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite follow what you are trying to do with the "test" expression but if the SQL mentioned is to be achieved, I guess a simple query like this should do:

```
Dim Result = (
    From i in dt.Rows
    Group By f1 = i("f1"), f2 = i("f2"), f3 = i("f3")
    Into f4 = Sum(i("f4"))
    ).ToList
```

**UPDATE: METHOD SYNTAX**

```
Dim Data = datarows.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .f1 = x("f1"), Key .f2 = x("f2"), Key .f3 = x("f3")}).Select(Function(x) New With {.f1 = x(0)("f1"), .f2 = x(0)("f2"), .f3 = x(0)("f3"), .f4 = x.Sum(Function(i) i(3))}).ToList
```

Comment: But this isn't a method syntax on one side, on the another I think, I described the issue sufficiently detailed. I just want to integrate the sum function (or another aggregate function) in the last codeblock.

Comment: @derstauner, I have added the same query in method syntax to my answer. I hope it works out for you.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I have already the sum function in the query, but my problem is, that the values of f4 are not summed. You can try it, if you copy & paste the code in vs.

Comment: @derstauner, I have read the question carefully, but there was a typo in my code. If you test it now, you will see that it returns a single row with "a", "b", "c", and the sum of f4. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will test it at home.